# How to convert a string variable to a char variable with a strict length?

Tags: c#, char

I want to convert a string variable into char that char variable will have a length 30 symbols always. I code in C#.

```
string str="aaa";
char[30] myChar = theString.ToCharArray();
```

And this code creates "myChar" with just 3 symbols. I want that "myChar" will be 30 symbols. How to do it?

Comment: Additionally, how do you want the "empty" array spaces to be initialized?

Comment: What should the other 27 array fields contain if your string is only 3 characters long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = new string('a',30).ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx):

```
string theString="aaa";
char[30] myChar = theString.PadRight(30).ToCharArray();
```

The overload I used will pad with spaces. You can use the second overload that takes a character as the second parameter to pad with that character.